# bindingsource.filter not working

Tags: c#, sql, binding

this does not work

```
string d = InvDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Trim();
            sale_invoiceBindingSource.Filter = "InvDate = '"+d+"'";
```

But this works

```
string d = InvDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Trim();
            sale_invoiceBindingSource.Filter = "InvDate = '20/12/2013 10:45 PM'";
```

Cant figure out whats the problem

Answer (score 0):

if your filter accepts date format in `dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt` format you dont need to provide seconds (`ss`)

Try This:

```
string d = InvDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Trim();
sale_invoiceBindingSource.Filter = "InvDate = '"+d+"'";
```